# Problem with instantiating chaincode in Hyperledger fabric Network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have a problem with instantiating chaincode in Hyperledger fabric Network with comm:

```
peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.ex.com:7050 -C roaming -n chaincode  -v 1.1 -c '{"Args":[]}' -P "AND ('ORG1MSP.member')" --tls --cafile /etc/hyperledger/fabric/config/ca.crt
```

The peer is joined the channel and chaincode is installed on it.

The log of orderer is:

```
ERRO 029 TLS handshake failed with error tls: oversized record received with length 64774 server=Orderer

WARN 02a Error reading from 172.16.0.81:34562: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled

INFO 02b streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=172.16.0.81:34562 error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" grpc.code=Canceled grpc.call

WARN 02c Error reading from 172.16.0.81:35318: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
```

In the log of the peer - nothing interesting.

Comment: Have you checked the format and contents of your ca.crt file?  afaik it should start with the ---BEGIN CERTIFICATE--- line and end with END CERTIFICATE and have the other lines chopped at about 60 characters.

Comment: Yes, I checked it not just how it looks, but with openssl command. Thanks for comment.

Answer (score 0):

The error looks like the client is trying to communicate speak HTTP/GRPC to a server expecting HTTPS/GRPCS (or viceversa)

If your fabric network endpoints are not encrypted, remove the `--tls` and `--cafile` flags.

Otherwise, make sure to use an encrypted endpoint for the orderer (e.g. `orderer.ex.com:443` if it's exposed via HTTPS with an ingress controller) and the peer as well (`CORE_PEER_ADDRESS`)

I have also found when enabling TLS that the following environment variables are needed in addition to the `--tls` and `--cafile` above:

```
CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/path/to/ca/pem  (e.g. `letsencryptauthorityx3.pem`)
CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
```